# Deleting records in trigger

Tags: trigger

I want to delete the newly created account in salesforce. Please advise on the following code in the screenshot , if it is possible to delete the record using trigger.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
trigger HelloWorldTrigger on Account(after Insert){
   List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
   for(Account acc : [select id from account where id IN :trigger.new){
      accList.add(acc);
   }
   if(!accList.isEmpty()){
     Delete accList;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it's possible to do that, it is probably worth considering other options for achieving your goal. One problem with the previous answer is that you will most likely send your user to a "Looks like there's a problem..." page - Salesforce will typically redirect the user to the new record (which no longer exists, since you deleted it, hence you get this error page). As a general point of good practice / common sense, it is inefficient to hit the database with an insert only to delete the record immediately after.

I'm guessing you're doing something else in the trigger, like capturing the input details, or deleting the account conditionally. If you're using Lightning, flows might suit your needs better. Otherwise, perhaps custom objects? You could, for example, create a "Account Request" object with a scheduled job that reads the Account Requests and determines whether they meet X and Y criteria, then either create the accounts or do some kind of rejection notification.